# Passing Local Parameters to Hadoop script

Tags: hadoop, hive, command-line-arguments

To my understanding, the following will result in passing a global Hive variable:

```
   hive -hiveconf DATE='01/01/2000' -f test_script.hql
```

That can be called with

```
   SELECT * FROM DATETABLE WHERE DATE = ${hiveconf:DATE}
```

And I know that local variables can be defined in the script and called by doing:

```
   set DATE='01/01/2000'
   SELECT * FROM DATETABLE WHERE DATE = ${DATE}
```

But say one wanted to submit many jobs with local parameters set for each script, how can we pass them from the command line?

The emphasis is avoiding one script picking up the `hiveconf:DATE` set by another script that was submitted in quick succession.

EDIT:

I guess this could work, creating a shell script and passing variables to the shell script and then passing those to the individual queries:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    FIRST_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM DATETABLE WHERE DATE = '$DATE'"

    hive -e "$FIRST_QUERY"
```

But this seems inefficient, I would still want to know if the option above is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the option `-define` [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli):

```
hive -e 'SELECT * FROM DATETABLE WHERE DATE = ${DATE}' -define DATE='01/01/2000'
```